# Charge per installation of g-suite application?

Tags: gsuite-addons

I'm exploring how to develop some g-suite applications (eg. gmail add-on, spreadsheet add-on, etc...).   It's not clear to me whether the g-suite platform offers a payment API to let me charge customers $2.99 USD per installation?  Then google will automatically settle the sales revenue into our bank account?  I can't find any technical literature that confirms or denies the existence of this feature.

Or do I need to take a more **traditional approach** by directing the customer (eg. in the form of an iframe or something) to a page on my web server, where I integrate my own merchant service provider of choice (eg. paypal, stripe, etc...) to handle credit card payments?  Then I need to oauth2 authenticate them on my server, confirm their billing is in good standing, before providing access to paid features?

Comment: It was under [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/gsuite-restrictions) in the documentation. *We don't provide a way to charge users for installing add-ons, and add-ons can't include ads. However, you can roll your own payment system or call into an existing billing database. Your add-on can connect to non-Google services that bill users.*

Answer (score 1):

I think for your case you should go and read carefully the [G Suite Marketplace Developer Agreement](https://gsuite.google.com/terms/marketplace/devtos.html).

In there you have this line which explicity says that you would need to pay Google a "Listing Fee"

> 3.2 If you choose to distribute Products through the Market for a fee, you will pay Google a non-refundable listing fee ("Listing Fee") as set forth at https://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/fees.html.